# Awk as a conditional

Tags: csv, logging, awk, scripting

Ok so I've done some research and haven't found anything that seems to fit my issue and I'm new to shell scripting.  So if I have a csv file:
    abc,123,456,
    abc,123,456,
    abc,123,456,
    abc,123,456,

I want to check to see if the number of columns matches a variable passed in, using awk this isn't hard.

If there is a mismatch say:
 abc,123,456,
 abc,
 abc,123,456,
 abc,123,456,

a log is created specifying the line, what was expected and what actually was there.  The issue I'm having is trying to skip the process of logging if there is no mismatch.  I need to make it skip files where everything matches and just log files that have mismatches but everything I've tried seems to fail. Tries awks inside if statements, tried awks with if statements in them, multiple awks with a break or exit which just gave me syntax errors.  I'm at a loss. Any suggestions would be helpful.

The expected output is super simple.

filename
line  expected  actual
 2      3         1

there would be appropriate spacing between the numbers, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do the logging in `awk`, so if there is nothing to report there won't be any log records.

```
$ awk -F, -v r=3 'BEGIN {header="line expected actual"}
                  NF!=r {if(!p) print FILENAME "\n" header >> "log.txt";
                         print NR,r,NF >> "log.txt"; p=1 }' file
```

here we keep the state for printing the header information in the variable `p`, so it will be printed only once if there are any mismatches.  Otherwise the script will be silent.  Alternatively you can accumulate the mismatched lines and print at the `END` block.

You can avoid creating empty log files by moving the file print into the script as well.

Comment: couple of questions, 1) what is the p and 2) if it needs to go to a log file that is a collection of logs from various files this is used on would I just use >>log.txt at the end?

Comment: This works, thank you, but now it creates the log file i want to append to even if there is nothing to put in it, which is related to my second question in the above comment.

Comment: Thank you so much!